# Pymongo Querying a second collection based on the ObjectId that is linked in the first collection

Tags: python, pymongo

I am using pymongo and I have a collection lets call it "districts" I have some basic information about the district in the document. I Also have a referenced ObjectId for a "district_admin" which is located in a second collection called "district_admins". I'm to query all the districts and also have the object of that district admin included in that single query. What is my best appoach?

District Collection:

```
_id:ObjectId("jn2783h42837bd823sadf")
district_name:"Example District"
district_address:"123 Example Way"
district_admin:ObjectId("923874y32kjnkjnkjn")
```

District_admin Collection

```
_id:ObjectId("923874y32kjnkjnkjn")
first_name:"John"
last_name:"wayne"
```

Comment: It seems like you are looking for the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator

Comment: @styvane This worked! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like you are looking for the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator.
>   -– @styvane